# Are there any applications like SAP available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am in a business, and the company I am in uses [SAP](http://www.sap.com/).

Are there any applications like SAP available for Ubuntu?

Comment: SAP is a company providing different products, most of which have to do with database systems. Please specify, what product, or what kind of software you mean in particular.

Comment: The company i am in uses almost if not all products. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this: http://www.manager.io/

Works well, simple but good for small businesses

Comment: Just note Manager.io is proprietary software, you still have the vendor lock-in, the _Free Forever_ is as long as they stay in business.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 leading ERPs in the Open source world are:

- [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/) (aka OpenERP)
- [OpenBravo](http://www.openbravo.com/)

OpenBravo has become quite a bit commercial, and in my opinion, lost its open source friendliness...
Odoo looks more open source friendly, but is slowly approaching OpenBravo's business model.

Odoo offers SaS (Software as a service), by which if you are a small company and want to start trying this, you can pay them monthly a few dollars, and they will host the service for you. You will have all your data "in the cloud".